# How to change an input text class with radio buttons group with Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a radio Group with two radio buttons, and a input text for autocomplete. My goal is to use the radio button to change the class of input text. This way, I can autocomplete the input text using "cod" or "descricao" depending what radio button is selected.

I,ve tried:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">  

        $(document).ready( function($) 
        {                                   

            $(function()        
            {               
                $('input[name=buscarPor]:radio').click(function()
                {   
                    if($('#descricao').attr('checked'))
                    {
                        $('#term').attr('class', 'descricao');
                        $('#term').attr('placeholder', 'product name');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $('#term').attr('class', 'cod');
                        $('#term').attr('placeholder', 'product code');
                    }
                    $('#term').focus();
                });             
            });                 

            $('.descricao').autocomplete(
            {  
                source: 'buscaDesc.php',  
                minLength:2,                                        
                // optional                                 
                html: true,                                         
                // optional (if other layers overlap the autocomplete list)
                open: function (event, ui)                                      
                {                                                   
                    console.log($(this).val(ui.item.label));    

                    return false;                               
                },                                          
                select: function(event, ui)                     
                {                                           
                    $('#term').val(ui.item.value);
                    $('form#frmBusca').submit();
                }           
            });

            $('.cod').autocomplete(
            {  
                source: 'buscaCod.php',  
                minLength:2,                                        
                // optional                                 
                html: true,                                         
                // optional (if other layers overlap the autocomplete list)
                open: function (event, ui)                                      
                {                                                   
                    console.log($(this).val(ui.item.label));    

                    return false;                               
                },                                          
                select: function(event, ui)                     
                {                                           
                    $('#term').val(ui.item.value);
                    $('form#frmBusca').submit();
                }           
            });
        });                                 

    </script>
```

also tried with addClass and removeClass but either don't work.

Here goes the html

```
    <center>

        <div  style="width:400px">
            <form name="frmBusca" id="frmBusca" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">

                <div>   
                    <label style="width:300px; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold">Search product by:</label><br><br>

                    <label>Product name</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="buscarPor" id="descricao" style="width:20px;" value="descricao" /><br>

                    <label>Product Code</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <input type="radio" name="buscarPor" id="cod" style="width:20px;" value="cod"  checked  /><br><br>

                    <input type="text" style="width:150px;" name="term" id="term" class="cod" placeholder="Product code" value="" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

    </center>
```

And a simple PHP to verify:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant do that way.

**Quick answer**

Call .autocomplete everytime you add or remove class.

**Reason.**

When you call autocomplete for the first time it is only for the existing DOM. Once you change the class the DOM changes and the original autocomplete will not target your new DOM. So everytime you add class you need to call $().autocomplete again. Be sure to remove the previous autocomplete before you do though or you will have conflicting autocomplete. Also if you want to add or remove class stick with .addClass and .removeClass.

Comment: Ok, I'll be searching how to do this  :)  Thanks a lot !